# Green's theorem Area formula additional cases

Tags: greens-theorem

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199003/proving-greens-theorem-for-computing-area),  the OP states 3 area formulas and asks for proof.  The answer given uses 3 specific cases where  ∂Q/∂x − ∂P/∂y=1.  I see why these 3 cases give the area formulas, but what about other cases where the difference of partial derivatives = 1, but the specific values of P and Q  differ from the 3 cases given?   Could those cases produce area computations different from the ones given?

Comment: Yes, By applying Green's theorem, any pair of smooth functions satisfying $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 1$$ will give you the area when you integrate $\int_C P\,dx + Q\, dy$ around the boundary $C$.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I'm "thinking backwards".  I see that Green's Theorem proves these 3 formulas, but doesn't negate the possibility that other (less commonly used) formulas might be found for other functions satisfying the partial derivative equation.